# how to add identity column for a table using mysql server 5.6?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to create a table with an identity column. i used the below query.
using mysql server 5.6.

```
create table t1
{
id int identity(1,1) Primary key
name varchar2(10)
};
```

but it shows the below error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '{ id int identity(1,1) Primary key name
>   varchar2(10) }' at line 2

kindly help me with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `()` instead of `{}`

Here the sample

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp

Your answer should be

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   name VARCHAR2(10)
)
```

Refer from https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/652076-how-create-identity-column-mysql